# How do I create quarto snippets in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, quarto

I'm struggling to get snippets work in vscode with a Quarto file. I have followed all the steps and I am confused about this.

1. I've created the snippet in a `quarto.json` file. My snippet looks like this:

```json
{

    "Create NOTES section and place cursor inside": {
        "prefix": "nn",
        "body": [
            "<!-- BEGIN NOTES -->\n\n$1\n\n<!-- END NOTES -->"
        ],
        "description": "Create Notes section and place cursor inside"
    }

}
```

2. I've checked that the autosuggest options are enabled. My `settings.json` file has the following:

```json
    "[quarto]": {
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
          "other": true,
          "comments": true,
          "strings": true
        }
    }
```

However, in the Quarto file, no suggestions appear when I press `nn`.

NB the extension of the Quarto file is `.qmd` not `.Quarto`, but vscode recognises the file as a `quarto` file as (i) this appears in the footer of the `.qmd` window, and (ii) a `quarto.json` file automatically appears when I configure user snippets.

Comment: use `$0` to define the final cursor position, `$1` is a tab stop, still in snippet mode

Answer (score 6):

Okay. There are separate settings for Quarto (see below). If you go into settings, and search for Quarto it then shows you Quarto snippet settings. The Quarto help pages not describe this, and it might be useful to add this.

[image: image of Quarto options]